# Find coordinates inside borders coordinates

Tags: javascript, path-finding

I have x,y 4x5 dashboard. I have collisions array of objects which is:

```
const collisions = [{x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 2, y: 0}, {x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 0, y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 3}, {x: 2, y: 3}, {x: 3, y: 1}, {x: 3, y: 2}];
```

which basically make a square without edges. I also have array of destinations which is:

```
const destinations = [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 0, y: 4}];
```

the graphical representation is:

[image]

where red are `collisions` and gold are `destinations`.

I need algorithm which would find destinations which are surrounded by collisions. I can't walk diagonally so in above scenerio I want to find {x: 1, y:1}.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new algorithm I would probably try to use well-tested established (and already implemented) path finding algos like **A*** (which is basically an optimized version of Dijkstra's algorithm, read more about path finding algos [here](https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/path-finding-algorithms-f65a8902eb40)) and adapt your scenario so these can be used. I think this approach will save you quite some time and make your code more reliable.

Note that I converted your coordinate objects into arrays of coordinates, it is a) more common to express coordinates in this way and b) easier (and most likely faster => Arrays are fast) to work with them.

For your example we basically want to find a path to each destination from some point OUTSIDE of your actual grid. We also need to make sure the destinations that are on the edge of your grid, e.g. `[0,0]` and `[0,4]` are reachable in some way, e.g. a path can lead to them. For this reason we expand/"pad" the grid with one node on each side. That means all your coordinates shift by 1 node.

[image]

From there we can simply check if a path exists to a destination. I'm checking from `[0,0]` which is now outside of your actual grid, but you can check from anywhere as long as the node is one of the "padding" nodes:

```js
const collisions = [[1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]];
const destinations = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 4]];

// we expand the grid by one node on each side
// otherwise destinations at the edge might not be reachable!
const grid = new PF.Grid(4+2, 5+2);

// set up the blocked nodes
collisions.forEach(collision => {
 // +1 accounts for the grid "padding" of one node
 grid.setWalkableAt(collision[0]+1, collision[1]+1, false);
});

const paintGrid = grid => {
  const rects = [];
  const nodes = grid.nodes.flat();
  nodes.forEach(node => {
    rects.push(`
      <rect x="${node.x*24}" y="${node.y*24}" width="24" height="24" fill="${node.walkable ? '#FFF' : 'red'}" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0.2"></rect>
    `);
  });
  destinations.forEach(dest => {
    rects.push(`
      <rect x="${(dest[0]+1)*24}" y="${(dest[1]+1)*24}" width="24" height="24" fill="gold" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0.2"></rect>
    `);
  });
  document.querySelector('#grid').innerHTML = rects.join('');
};

const isTrapped = destination => {
 // make a working copy of the grid
 // as it will not be re-usable after processing
 const g = grid.clone();
 const finder = new PF.AStarFinder({
  allowDiagonal: false
 });
 
 // +1 accounts for the grid "padding" of one node
 return finder.findPath(0, 0, destination[0]+1, destination[1]+1, g).length === 0;
};

paintGrid(grid);

destinations.forEach(destination => {
 console.log(`is ${destination} trapped?`, isTrapped(destination));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/qiao/PathFinding.js@0.4.18/visual/lib/pathfinding-browser.min.js"></script>

<svg id="grid" width="144" height="168" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

</svg>
```

If you really need full blown path finding is of course depending on your real-world scenario, if your grid and destinations will always be that "small" in scale you could probably find an easier solution like the one suggested by @Yavuz Tas

Answer (score 1):

There may be more efficient algorithms to calculate this but at first thought, you can simply iterate all destinations and check their neighbor squares for all 4 directions (left, right, up, down) one by one.

Here is an implementation. It is a little verbose but you can simplify it by separating functions:

```
const collisions = [{x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 2, y: 0}, {x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 0, y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 3}, {x: 2, y: 3}, {x: 3, y: 1}, {x: 3, y: 2}];
const destinations = [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 0, y: 4}];

const surrounded = [];

// boundaries
var minX = 0, minY = 0;
var maxX = 3, maxY = 4;

var point = {x: 0, y: 0};
for(dest of destinations){

  var left = false;
  var right = false;
  var up = false;
  var down = false;

  point.x = dest.x;
  point.y = dest.y;

  // left check
  while(point.x--){

    // hit check
    if(collisions.findIndex(e => e.x==point.x&&e.y==point.y) > -1){
      // console.log("left hit for point:")
      // console.log(dest)
      left = true;
      break;
    }

    if(point.x <= minX || point.x >= maxX || point.y <= minY || point.y >= maxY){
      break;
    }

  }

  if(!left)
    continue;

  point.x = dest.x;
  point.y = dest.y;

  // right check
  while(point.x++){

    // hit check
    if(collisions.findIndex(e => e.x==point.x&&e.y==point.y) > -1){
      // console.log("right hit for point:")
      // console.log(dest)
      right = true;
      break;
    }

    if(point.x <= minX || point.x >= maxX || point.y <= minY || point.y >= maxY){
      break;
    }

  }

  if(!right)
    continue;

  point.x = dest.x;
  point.y = dest.y;

  // up check
  while(point.y--){

    // hit check
    if(collisions.findIndex(e => e.x==point.x&&e.y==point.y) > -1){
      // console.log("up hit for point:")
      // console.log(dest)
      up = true
      break;
    }

    if(point.x <= minX || point.x >= maxX || point.y <= minY || point.y >= maxY){
      break;
    }

  }

  if(!up)
    continue;

  point.x = dest.x;
  point.y = dest.y;

  // down check
  while(point.y++){

    // hit check
    if(collisions.findIndex(e => e.x==point.x&&e.y==point.y) > -1){
      // console.log("down hit for point:")
      // console.log(dest)
      down = true
      break;
    }

    if(point.x <= minX || point.x >= maxX || point.y <= minY || point.y >= maxY){
      break;
    }

  }

  if(!down)
    continue;

  if(left && right && up && down){
    surrounded.push(dest)
  }

}

console.log("Surrounded found: " + surrounded.length);
console.log(surrounded);
```

And here is [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/hicobuqaku/edit?js,console) for it.